# Integrating asp.net mvc with asp.net WebForm

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

There is a problem that I have two applications.

One is used ASP.NET MVC, while the other is used ASP.NET WebForm.
I wonder if there are some ways to integrate two applications.
You can say anything about the idea of the integration or show some links talk about this.
Thank!!!

PS: I do know that Asp.net Webform is out of time,so do not tell why not change the Webform to MVC.

Comment: Integration can be done like you can literally move all the files of the webforms into your MVC project. Else you can host both these applications under same domain..

Comment: I will try the first way ,what's the meaning of the second way?Which one is the main body?

Comment: Second way is that you will have both as two different projects but when you host it you can actually put them both under same domain.. Like `www.yourdoamin.com/mvc` and  `www.yourdomain.com/webform` .. If your interest is to integrate the source code then the first way is your choice.

Comment: http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/whats-new-in-visual-studio-2013/one-aspnet-integrating-aspnet-web-forms-mvc-and-web-api may this link will help you out.

Answer (score 0):

You could have them both as hybrid application. To do this (Visual Studio 2013+):

1. Click New Project > Web Forms, In the window select template as Web Forms and select options on Web Forms and MVC.
2. Add your existing files for Web Forms and MVC in the same solution.
3. Now config your `Global.asax` for MVC and declare appropriate routes and bind them in code.
   **Optional:** You could also Scaffold to have WebAPI in your solution.

You this [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38778/ASP-NET-WebForms-and-ASP-NET-MVC-in-Harmony) for details of implementation with sample project.